# Tiling with ten-fold symmetry and (unoriented) Penrose tiles?

Tags: co.combinatorics, tiling

Consider tilings of the plane made out of rhombi of side 1 and either angles $\pi/10$ and $2\pi/5$ or angles $\pi/5$ and $3\pi/10$. If we give a certain orientation to the edges and respect that orientation in our tiling, then, as is well known, we must have a Penrose tiling.

It is not hard to show that a Penrose tiling cannot contain this sort of pattern:

[image]

(picture taken from https://arxiv.org/pdf/2211.08239.pdf)

But what happens if we remove the orientation? Can we have that pattern (without the red arcs that show orientation, obviously) and extend it to a tiling of the entire plane by our two kinds of rhombi, preferrably keeping 10th-fold symmetry?

Obviously, such a tiling would have to be non-periodic, since a lattice cannot have 10th-fold symmetry.

(The fact a Spanish tiling company sells such a tiling (https://todobarro.com/suelo/coleccion-penrose/) makes me suspect one might exist, though something tells me they may not have actually extended it to all of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

[image]

EDIT: in order to avoid simple solutions, let us forbid tilings where only one of the two kinds of tiles is used outside a finite neighborhood.

Comment: That also raises the question: if you remove the orientations from an actual Penrose tiling (with 5-fold symmetry), can you complete the intersection of the tiling with an arbitrarily large ball in a "boring" way (periodic, or one-tile, etc.)?

Answer (score 7):

If you impose no other restrictions, something like this works just fine:

[image]

For a slightly more complicated variant incorporating both tile shapes:

[image]

Comment: Right, I thought I had forbidden the first option with my wording ("... by our two kinds of rhombi"). The second option also involves only one of the two tiles outside a bounded neighborhood. What happens if one also forbids that?

Comment: @HAHelfgott: In the second tiling, you can see "inward-pointing arrows" where two lines of thin rhombs at opposite orientations meet along edges. For every point in each such arrow, one can insert a fat rhomb in between them, leaving the rest of the arrow pointing outwards (and creating a new inward-pointing arrow). By repeatedly doing this to whichever inward-facing arrows remain, we can get infinitely many fat rhombs. (I can include a diagram later if this description isn't clear.)

Comment: Ah yes. (a) Does this procedure give all possible tilings with 10-fold symmetry and a star in the middle? (b) Note that the tilings produced by this procedure have the property that, for every radius R, one can take the part of our tiling inside a ball of radius R around the origin, and complete it as a tiling of the plane in a "boring" way ( = using only one kind of tile). Are there tilings with 10th fold symmetry that do not have this property. (This is analogous to the strong version of the definition of "aperiodic".)

Comment: @HAHelfgott: It's not clear to me that genuine Penrose tilings even have this property? E.g. [here's](https://i.imgur.com/jE51Bam.png) an incomplete diagram demonstrating that one common chunk of a Penrose tiling can be extended only using thin rhombs.

Comment: That's a really small neighborhood! But yes, let me look...

Answer (score 2):

There are tiles with this star in the center. It also has inflation as you see in the image:

[image: (image)]

These are not Penrose tilings since they do not follow the same rules in its creation.

Answer (score 0):

I think pages 364/365 in Kari, Lutfalla; Substitution Discrete Plane Tilings with 2n-Fold Rotational Symmetry; Discrete & Computational Geometry (2023) 69:349–398 https://doi.org/10.1007/s00454-022-00390-z give an example and some theory.